# How to increase the html textbox characters length

Tags: html, database

i am trying to store 100 characters in database but 30 characters are store in database remaining characters are not store in database please give me suggestions to increase the characters length of html textbox

Comment: by default html textbox doesn't have length limit.

Comment: This is definately a database issue. You wouldn't be able to type the full string/query/etc. if the max-length was set on the text-box. Change the field length to 100!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="100" />
```

unless your database field is only a varchar(30), in which case you'd have to do an `ALTER TABLE` to expand it to 100 characters.

You've provided insufficient detail to figur eout exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

it depends if that is comment field give text properties for that .. it will take..

or if it is name, username , give varchar(100) it will take..

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964